# Single line of text not allowing symbols

Tags: list

We have a field for a monetary value. I am using "Single line of text" instead of Currency because some values will be in GBP and some in Euros. When a currency symbol is used the list item won't save. Are symbols allowed in "Single line of text"?

Answer (score 0):

£$ are allowed in single line of text. Verify if you have any other column or event receiver that is dependent on the "failing" column.

Comment: Nope nothing else uses this column

Comment: Add another temporary column as Single line of text and make sure you can store £$ in that column. Also make sure that the validation section is empty.

Comment: Validation section is empty. Other Single line of text column accepts £. Curiouser and curiouser....